# Import data from csv file - Why did they print different things?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Take the following code:

```
import csv
# import items with first row
inputfile = open('price.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
rows1 = [row for row in reader] # here
# del first row
rows2 = rows1[1:]
print(rows2)
```

Changing

```
rows1 = [row for row in reader]
```

into

```
rows1 = [row for row in inputfile]
```

changes the output:

```
# with 'reader'
[['6004', '240'], ['6004', '350'], ['6004', '350']]

# with 'inputfile'
['6004,240\n', '6004,350\n', '6004,350\n']
```

What caused that? Or to say, what is the principle?

Comment: csv reader make each line a list separated by commas whereas when you are simply reading the file you get each line as a string .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file` objects are iterable. Iterating over the `file` object `inputfile` returns raw (unparsed) lines as string objects.

You construct a `csv.reader` object which can parse those lines. The `csv.reader` object is also iterable, and iterating over it returns lists of strings for the individual CSV records.

Therefore you get different results when looping over `inputfile` than over `reader`.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not strip off newline when you read the lines by iterating or use functions like `readline`/`readlines` for that matter. If all your lines end in newline, you can strip it off manually.

Another thing is, `csv.reader` reads the lines from the file object and creates an iterator of lists where each list contains the values of the lines splitted on `,` or whatever separator you've set, taking into account quoting and other nuances.

So, for your example, to get a somewhat similar behavior, you can do:

```
[row[:-1].split(',') for row in inputfile]
```

Comment: Splitting on commas is not the same as what the `csv` module does: in particular, CSV files can contain quoted values that can contain comma characters.

Comment: @DanielPryden Clarified.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the white spaces explicitly while iterating over the file object inputfile

```
rows1=[row.strip() for row in inputfile]
```